# How to manually add Alamofire into xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks, alamofire

I couldn't integrate alamofire into my project. I drag & drop "Source" folder [[this folder]](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/tree/master/Source) into my project directory after download and unzip the alamofire framework from github. But i got multiple errors specifically in manager.swift file, Response.swift file & ResponseSerialization.swift file. I also can't import Alamofire as it shows "No such module Alamofire". How can i add alamofire to my project manually ? I don't want to use podcast.

Edited : Error that i got in different files -

Manager.swift file :
[image: Manager.swift]

Request.swift file :
[image: Request.swift]

RequestSerialization.swift file :
[image: RequestSerialization.swift]

Comment: Can you please post the errors?

Comment: Edited the question with error images that i got in different files of Alamofire after download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the latest `Alamofire` which is based on Swift 2.2 and you are running on lower Xcode version.

Run your app on Xcode 7.3 with the latest `Alamofire` version and your problem will be solved.